# Firebase Polymer delete file from storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, firebase-storage

I want to delete some files from firebase storage

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/summit.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

These are my storage rules.
I wanted to test the feature by using a demo function

```
  _demoremove: function() {

    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(); 
    // Create a reference to the file to delete
    var desertRef =   storageRef.child('https://firebasestorage.google'); //i js copied a download-url from my one of the files in the storage

    // Delete the file
    desertRef.delete().then(function() {
      // File deleted successfully
      console.log('done');
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
```

Is there anything wrong with this format? I am getting an error `object is not found`

Answer (score 1):

Why did you put a URL inside your desertRef? There should not be your download link. However it should store the path of your storage file. Example:

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage();
var desertRef = storageRef.child("/images/image.jpg");
```